# how to test the batch code?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, scheduled-apex

How to write test class for this code 75% coverage or not?

```
 global class SearchAndUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Schedulable
 {

    global final String Query;
    public Set<String> LstString = new Set<String>();
    Public List<Demand__c> Lst1 = new list<Demand__c>();
    Public List<IDC_Demand__c> IDCDemandlst = new list<IDC_Demand__c>();

    global SearchAndUpdate()
    {      
      Query = 'Select Id,RRD_Number__c,idc_chek__c FROM Demand__c';             
      IDCDemandlst = [Select RRD_Number__c FROM IDC_Demand__c];
      if(IDCDemandlst.size()>0)
      {
          for(IDC_Demand__c IDCD : IDCDemandlst)
          {
              LstString.add(IDCD.RRD_Number__c);
          }     
       }       
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    { 
       return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Demand__c> Lst)
    {
      if(Lst.size()>0)
      {
         for(Demand__c d : Lst)
         {
            if(LstString.contains(d.RRD_Number__c))
            {
                d.idc_chek__c= 'Yes';
                Lst1.add(d);
            }
            else if(!LstString.contains(d.RRD_Number__c))
            {
                d.idc_chek__c= 'No';
                Lst1.add(d);
            }
         }
     }
     if(Lst1.size()>0)update Lst1;
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC)
    {
        SearchAndUpdate obj = new SearchAndUpdate();
        database.executeBatch(obj);
    }

     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
   }
```

Comment: Where is the code that you wrote? did you try anything? just follow the rules for test class.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic how we test the batch apex class

```
@isTest

public class YOURCLASSTEST{ 

static testmethod void myBirthdayControllerTest(){
SAMPLE p=new SAMPLE__C();// INSERT SOME JUNK DATA 

p.Name__c='Test';
p.Email__c='test@force.com';
p.DOb__c=System.now().date();
insert p;

Test.StartTest();// AS BATCH IS A ASYNC PROCESS , HENCE USING START TEST & STOP TEST 
    YOUR BATCH_APEX_CLASS_NAME mbc= new BATCH_APEX_CLASS_NAME();

    mbc.query = 'SELECT Id,name,Name__c,Email__c,DOb__c FROM OBJECT NAME ' ;// WHERE YOU WANT TO QUERY

         ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(mbc);



    Test.StopTest();

    }
    }
```

Comment: Your on the correct path with this answer, though you can improve it further i think, not only for today, but in the future when others come across the same question. Improving it will also attract more up votes if you consider perhaps tidying up the code so its easier to read and explaining more what is going on. Perhaps also some links to the documentation where people can read more what Salesforce has to say on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for your advise @AndrewFawcett ,Wl improve as per your suggestion in my next answer

Comment: Note also that if the batch class does callouts (which this doesn't), the testing strategy is more complex - see http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/06/18/batchable-class-test-data-callouts-how-to-test/

Comment: @crop1645 - Holy crap I have been looking for a way to resolve that issue. Thank you so much. I stopped searching 6 months ago as there was no resolution. Thank you!